# How to format json output in pyspark?

Tags: json, pyspark

I am having a trouble to preserve the order of my json and pretty printing it in pyspark.

Below is sample code:

```
json_out = sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize([json.dumps(info)]))

# here info is my ordered dictionary

json_out.toJSON().saveAsTextFile("file:///home//XXX//samplejson")
```

One more thing is that I want my output as single file and not as partitioned datasets.

Could anyone help in pretty printing and preserving the order of output json in my case?

info sample:

Note:TypeA,TypeB etc is a list meaning there can be more than one product in TypeA or TypeB.

```
{
  "score": {
    "right": ,
    "wrong": 
  },
  "articles": {
    "TypeA": [{
      "ID": 333,
      "Name": "",
      "S1": "",
      "S2": "",
      "S3": "",
      "S4": ""
    }],
    "TypeB": [{
      "ID": 123,
      "Name": "",
      "T1": "",
      "T2": "",
      "T3": "",
      "T4": "",
      "T5": "",
      "T6": ""
    }]    
  }
}
```

( I have tried using json.dumps(info,indent=2),but of no use.